# Running VM of a physical hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, hyper-v, disk-management

I have an old hard drive with Windows XP on it from very long ago. I want to get back into the OS and see it. I'm trying to get run it in a Hyper-V machine on my workstation/gaming PC (Windows 10 Pro, GTX 1080, Ryzen 1700x, 16GB 3200 MHz). I have other Hyper-V machines working, but I can't figure out how to make it work. The drive is going to a SATA port on my motherboard, and I took the drive offline in Disk Management. I did however mark all the partitions as raw which seem like it's not a problem, but I'm not sure.

Disk Management:

[image: Disk Management]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Have you run Disk2VHD to convert the disk into an image?

Comment: and then I just use that for a new vm?

Comment: @spikey_richie I am trying that and I get error snashotting volumes.

Comment: Do you have enough room to store the .VHD file? I assume you're saving the .VHD to a different drive...

Comment: yes i have more than a tb free and the hard drive im trying to image is only 250 gb

Comment: You don’t indicate what error you receive.  How are we supposed to answer your question?  Of course if the partitions are raw then there isn’t a file system.

Comment: I think you should bring the disk online first. That's in case you are trying to do Disk2VHD conversion in the state you showed on the screenshot. As an alternative you can use StarWind V2V converter to do P2V of your drive. 
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/v2v-help/PhysicalDisksandP2VScenario.html